# How do I enable javascript in webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I have a web application which launches a windows application using Citrix server.

Windows application has a webbrowser control.

When windows application is launched stand alone on Citrix server, web site opens in webbrowser control with no problem.

But when it is launched through my web application, the webbrowser control does not load the javascript. 
It shows content blocked error. It does not fire any event and show message on web page as

**"Note: Since your browser does not support javascript you must press the Continue button once to proceed
"**

I tried this :

I enabled the scripting on Internet Explorer on Citrix server.

Added my application url in trusted site.

But none of the above worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice walkthrough if you would be compelled to do something like work in IE.

https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/how-to-enable-javascript/internet-explorer